# Railway Oriented Programming - function output not passing through

Tags: f#

I've been working my way through [this article on ROP](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/), and have reached the section "*Converting simple functions to the railway-oriented programming model*" where he explains how to fit other kinds of functions into the model.

He gave the example of wanting to clean an email address (function name different as I'm English!)...

```
let cleanEmail person =
  printfn "Cleaning email for \"%s\"" person.Name
  let newPerson = { person with Email = person.Email.Trim().ToLower() }
  printfn "  email is now \"%s\"" newPerson.Email
  newPerson
```

I added some printfn to see what was happening. This function works fine, in that if I pass it an input with an email that has uppercase letters and/or leading/trailing blanks, the output is a value with a clean, lowercase email address...

```
let shouter = { Name = "Jim"; Email = "  JIM@SHOUT.com "}
cleanEmail shouter
```

Gives the output...

```
Cleaning email for "Jim"
  email is now "jim@shout.com"
val it : Request = {Name = "Jim";
                    Email = "jim@shout.com";}
```

However, if I wrap this function in a switch, and insert it into the chain of validation functions, the original email address is used. For example, with validation functions like this...

```
let validateNameNotBlank person =
  printfn "Validating name not blank for \"%s\"" person.Name
  if person.Name = "" then Failure "Name must not be blank"
  else Success person
```

...an operator like this...

```
let (>=>) switch1 switch2 input =
  match switch1 input with
  | Success s -> switch2 input
  | Failure f -> Failure f
```

...and bound together like this...

```
let validate =
  validateNameNotBlank
  >=> validateNameLength
  >=> switch cleanEmail
  >=> validateEmail
```

...then when I pass shouter in, I get the following out...

```
Validating name not blank for "Jim"
Validating name length for "Jim"
Cleaning email for "Jim"
  email is now "jim@shout.com"
Validating email for "Jim" (  JIM@SHOUT.com )
val it : Result<Request,string> = Success {Name = "Jim";
                                       Email = "  JIM@SHOUT.com ";}
```

You can see from the printfn I put in that the cleanEmail function is cleaning the email, but the output shows that the original email is passed to the next function in the chain.

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the article, the operator has the definition

```
let (>=>) switch1 switch2 x = 
    match switch1 x with
    | Success s -> switch2 s
    | Failure f -> Failure f
```

which when correctly translated to your variables is:

```
let (>=>) switch1 switch2 input =
  match switch1 input with
  | Success s -> switch2 s
  | Failure f -> Failure f
```

You never actually use the `s` from the `Success` so the same input just keeps getting passed through.

A close examination of the type of `>=>` would have revealed this problem as yours would have given the same type to `switch1` and `switch2` when they should have different types.

Comment: Duh, silly me! Instead of copying and pasting his code, I was typing it in myself (in order to make me stop and think about it). I must have misread his code and typed the wrong thing. Thanks for the correction and explanation.